# How to store cookies in an Android WebView?

Tags: java, php, android, cookies, android-webview

Currently I'm trying to store cookies in my android app. My app is loading a web page using the android webview. The activity is below.

But, I need help to store cookies in my app. The web page I'm loading is creating the cookies with php using the `setcookie()` function. It works fine in a regular browser, but I'm a beginner app developer and it doesn't work in my android WebView.

I need your help to store the cookie with php (on the loaded web page).

P.S. I want the cookie to last forever (if possible).

```
package com.stuff;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Activity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        // Let's display the progress in the activity title bar, like the
        // browser app does.
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);

        WebView webview = new WebView(this);
        setContentView(webview);


        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        final Activity activity = this;
        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
             // Activities and WebViews measure progress with different scales.
             // The progress meter will automatically disappear when we reach 100%
             activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);
        }
      });

webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        //Users will be notified in case there's an error (i.e. no internet connection)
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
});
     //This will load the webpage that we want to see
      webview.loadUrl("http://www.need-cookies.com/");

   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the CookieSyncManager class, basically you can do this:

```
CookieSyncManager syncManager = CookieSyncManager.createInstance(webView.getContext());
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();

cookieManager.setCookie(); // Here your cookie
syncManager.sync();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm totally new to Android. Sorry, but where in my code would I add this? Also I'll be able to create my cookies in php and retrieve them using php also right? Thanks, you rock!

Comment: Yes with the cookiemanager instance  you can also call a getCookie(); function. You can call this after you are creating the webView instance: WebView webview = new WebView(this);

Comment: So to clarify I'll be able to use this setcookie() function... http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp                                  Inside my php script which in this case would be located on need-cookies.com

Comment: To be more clear need-cookies.com might be this... <?php setcookie("Cookie","Cookie_value",time()+1000000) ?>

Comment: 2 seconds on google: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html#getCookie(java.lang.String)

Comment: I still don't understand what I put in set cookie... (You know I'm already creating the cookie in php on my site)